# Spring cloud config with github

Tags: github, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I just got a problem when using spring cloud config with github.I'm not really good at English,I hope I could explained this problem clearly.And thinks 
 you guys for reading this.

The problem is about Spring Cloud Config with github.And it happened when I added some more folds and config files to the repository where hold all my cloud config files.

First,I set uri,searchPaths,username,password under the cloud.config.server.git in the application.yml file belonged to config server.

Then,I push all my config files to the github.I called the parent repository ConfigRepo,and in this repo,I got two folders named A and B.
The construction is just look like this.

```
-ConfigRepo   
  -A
    -A.yml   
  -B
    -B.yml
```

Finally,I set the other applications' application name in their bootstrap.yml which means A and B.

After I've done that,I started my applications.All the client servers could find the config server and got the correct config yml file by the url.For example, the client A get its configs from

> github.com/user/ConfigRepo/A/A.yml

But cause I needed to add a new application C,so I created a new folder C to hold and save the Application C's config file and push it to the github.

I finished the config work of application C just like above and start the it.But I found the url represent config file has changed.I mean,it suppose to be

> github.com/user/ConfigRepo/C/C.yml

But in fact,the url of github has changed to

> github.com/user/ConfigRepo/**tree/master**/C/C.yml

The worse thing is,not only the url represents C's config file has changed,all the url represents config file in the ConfigRepo has changed.

And no matter how i change the uri or searchPaths under cloud.config.server.git,the client server's log shows me that the name of located property source's mapPropertySource always is

> github.com/user/ConfigRepo/C/C.yml

As a result,i cant get any configs except null so all the applications cant be started even include the A and B which could started before i pushed the new config file to the github.

So,what should I do?Is a way to make github get rid of /tree/master in the url?Or how to config my config server to support my project?

Thanks Again!

Comment: Sorry,it was my fault. Spring Cloud Config has done its work well,there was something spelling mistake in my yml file.Spring Cloud Config could retrieve informations from github no matter if the url contains the "tree/master" part and there is no need for it to log that part.Thanks  again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are doing micro service project and used below configuration for retrieve configuration from GitHub. you need to add label as master to retrieve configuration.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: ####
  profiles:
    active: ####
  cloud:
    enable: true
    config:
      uri: ${CONFIG_SERVER_URL}
      failFast: true
      retry:
        maxAttempts: 20
      label: master
      profile: ######
```

Comment: Hi,bro,thanks for answering. I thought the label "master" is provided by Spring defaultly so I didn't add it to my client server config.But after i changed it just like you said,it still cant work.Seems like it still try to send request to "github.com/user/ConfigRepo/C/C.yml",but this url is not exist actually.For some reason,after I add some more files to that repository of my github,the url has changed to "github.com/user/ConfigRepo/tree/master/C/C.yml". In other words,before I add those file to the repository,the url didnt contain the "tree/master" part and all the application work well....

Comment: Checked my code again,it's was my fault.There was a spelling mistake in my yml file but all my attention was caught by the log of url.Thanks again bro.